# Assigning to 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned long *') from incompatible type 'const uint8_t *const' (aka 'const unsigned char *const')

Tags: objective-c, variables, methods

I'm relatively new to programming in objective c so please don't kill me for this question. 
Currently I'm working on a small program which should be able to make some changes to id3 tags of mp4 files. I've implanted the mp4v2 library and now I'm trying to write a method that reads out the tag informations of a specific file. 
My problem is that I just cannot get the value of the tag "contentRating" into a NSUInteger var. The reference of the library says that I get a value like this: "const uint8_t *".
But how can I put this into a NSUInteger var?
Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Heres my code:

```
- (void)getSongInfo:(NSString *)path
          title:(NSString *)t
          album:(NSString *)alb
         artist:(NSString *)art
         rating:(NSUInteger *)r
       albumart:(NSData *)aArt {

// Transform path in const char
const char *cPath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Load File
MP4FileHandle mp4File = MP4Modify(cPath);

// Create Tag var
const MP4Tags* tags = MP4TagsAlloc();

// Get Tags
MP4TagsFetch(tags, mp4File);

// Get Titel + Album + Interpret + Rating
t = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->name];
alb = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->album];
art = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->artist];

r = tags->contentRating; <-- My Problem!
```

Comment: You know that this won't modify `t`, `alb`, `art`, `r` and `aArt`? In C, arguments are always passed by value.

Comment: As I said, I'm like a total noob. So what do I do? I need to get all the values back for another method?

Comment: You pass pointers and dereference them. Google "C pass by pointer".

Comment: I'll see what I can find. Thanks so far ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
- (void)getSongInfo:(NSString *)path
      title:(NSString **)t
      album:(NSString **)alb
     artist:(NSString **)art
     rating:(NSUInteger *)r
   albumart:(NSData **)aArt {

 ...

// Get Titel + Album + Interpret + Rating
*t = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->name];
*alb = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->album];
*art = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tags->artist];

*r = (NSUInteger)(*tags->contentRating); <-- My Problem!
```

You would call this code like this:

```
NSString* title = nil;
NSString* album = nil;
NSString* artist = nil;
NSUInteger rating = 0;
NSData* albumArt = nil;

[self getSongInfo:path title:&title album:&album artist:&artist rating:&rating albumArt:&albumArt];
```

Respect to your code, my code contains two kind of changes:

1. arguments are passed by reference (so you can "pass back" a value to the caller);
2. `*contentRating` is being cast to the proper type (since NSUInteger is larger than `uint8_t`, this cast won't present any problem.

On the other hand, I would strongly suggest creating a class to hold the information about a song:

```
@interface MP3Info : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
...
@end
```

and the redeclare your method like:

```
- (MP3Info*)getSongInfo:(NSString *)path;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks sergio, you helped me a lot. Don't worry I've already created a class for the informations. I just needed a method to get the values to create objects.

Comment: Well I just wanted to know whether my changes to my function where correct or not. So I posted the link to pastbin where I uploaded my code ;)

Comment: sorry, did not see the link... your function seems ok; you might spare the local variables and directly pass the init method the proper values, if you like making your method shorter...